# SIGSEGV Crash but unable to collect backtrace

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

Information about the application:

- Linux - 2.4.1 Kernel
- m68k based embedded application
- Single process multithreaded application

We have an application where we have implemented the connection for the SIGSEGV with a segmentation_handler function. In this segmentation handler we create a file, do a file write (like "obtained stack frame"), then using backtrace and symbols write all the stack trace into the same file.

Problem: We get a SIGSEGV (confirmed due to creation of the log file) but unfortunately the file is empty (0kb file) with no information in it. (Even the first string which is a plain string is not available in the file).

I want to understand in what scenarios such a thing can happen because we can solve the crash if we get the stack trace, but we don't have it and the mechanism to get it did not work either :(

```
void segmentation_handler(int signal_no) { 
    char buffer[512]; ............. 
    InitLog();//Create a log file 
    printf("\n*** segmentation fault occured ***\n");
    fflush(stdout); 
    memset(buffer, 0, 512); 
    size = backtrace (array, 50); 
    strings = backtrace_symbols (array, size); 
    sprintf(buffer, "Obtained %d stack frames.\n", size); 
    Log(buffer);// Write the buffer into the file 
    for (n = 0; n < size; n++) { 
        sprintf(buffer, "%s\n", strings[n]); Log(buffer); 
    } 
    CloseLog();
}
```

Comment: What are you core size limits set to - check result of either 'limit -a' or 'ulimit -a'

Comment: <pre>core file size        (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size         (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size             (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory     (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size       (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                    (-n) 1024
pipe size          (512 bytes, -p) 8
stack size            (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time             (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes            (-u) 1024
virtual memory        (kbytes, -v) unlimited<code>

Comment: My apologies. And thanks shodanex for adding the code above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your segmentation handler is  very naive and contains multiple errors. Here is a short list:

1. You are calling fprintf() and multiple other functions which are not async signal safe. Consider, fprintf uses a lock internally to synch multiple calls to the same file descriptor from multiple threads. What if your segmentation fault was in the middle of printf and the lock was taken? you would dead lock in the middle of the segmentation handlers...
2. You are allocating memory (call to backtrace_symbols), but if the segmentation fault was due to malloc arena corruption (a very likely cause of segmentation violations) you would double fault inside the segmentation handler.
3. If multiple threads cause an exception in the same time the code will open multiple times the file and run over the log.

There are other problems, but these are the basics...

There is a video on my lecture on how to write proper fault handlers available here: http://free-electrons.com/pub/video/2008/ols/ols2008-gilad-ben-yossef-fault-handlers.ogg

Comment: Thanks for the guidance will improve the segmentation handler.

Comment: Saw the video and it was very informative. I have implemented in same way but have one question. I checked pthread spinlock is not available for me to use. can i use pthread mutex instead. I knwo your video says to use spin lock for async safety but i need help in understanding further.

Comment: A mutex is fine as long as you never try to lock it from the application - only from the segmentation handler

Comment: Thanks @gby one more question. In your video you wrote the entire crash struct into the file|pipe using write. Now how do you read from it since they will be clumsy looking symbols. Do we need to parse them or is there a more human readble format that can be employed. Since usage of sprintf and printf is not allowed because of async safety. I have a few more things to write like date time etc but it must be in a readable format.

Comment: Hi @gby. Thanks i got the following two lines in the top most lines in the back trace (Line1: /lib/libpthread.so.0[0x40300d18]
[0xbcbfc7d0] Line2: /lib/libc.so.6(vsprintf+0x7c)[0x4021cf74]) My old segmentation handler was just able to create the file ut was not able to log anything, The new segmentation handler worked like charm and gave the output. with complete back trace. Now the problem is to resolve this vsprintf related problem.

Answer (score 3):

- Remove the segmentation handler.
- Allow the program to dump core (ulimit -c unlimited or setrlimit in process)
- see if you have a core file.
- do the backtrace thing offline using your toolchain debugger

You can also write a program that segfault on purpose, and test both method (ie post mortem using the core file, or in signal handler).

Comment: Hi i am able to create core dump and looking into debugging it. Once successful will let all know. Thanks for the suggestions.